# Left aligning a QTreeView expand/collapse image using Qt Style Sheets

Tags: css, qt

My QTreeView has a bunch of branch-open/branch-closed arrows. I would like them all to be along the far left. i.e.,

```
> blah
  > blerg
      ..
      ..
  > blum
      ..
      ..
```

This would become:

```
> blah
>   blerg
      ..
      ..
>   blum
      ..
      ..
```

I have thus far been unsuccessful in deploying qt style sheets. I have tried all sorts of stuff. Here's my random last example:

qApp->setStyleSheet("QTreeView::branch:open:has-children {position:relative; text-align:left; margin-left: 0;}");

My stylesheets definitely do stuff sometimes. But never anything resembling the right thing.

Comment: If you could throw together a quick jsfiddle I could help you out.

Comment: `position:relative` replace with `position:absolute`

Comment: Here's ane xample tree: http://ibin.co/1IRRzLdlv204

Note that I want all arrows to be on the left column, without otherwise affecting the text. Using position:absolute didn't fix it. I have tried a lot of things including that.. is it even possible?